# Compiling & sharing static iPhone library -- issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

I am facing a strange issue while compiling my own static library. My library is referring to some other libs and hence in my Target build settings I have give "Library Search Path" to these libs. Now, when I compile and share this static lib & other libs which my static lib needs with other project it fails on compilation as it tend to search for these libs in the path I specified when building the static lib.

If I remove the "Library Search Path" contents while compiling my static lib, it fails at compilation time. I am totally stuck here.

Comment: Maybe a compiler/linker output or error log will help us to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALong with setting up **Header Search Path** , Try setting up the **Other Linkers Flag** too..

Go to “Other Linker Flags” under the “Linker” section, and add “-ObjC” and “-all_load” to the list of flags

Hope that works for you,